# How do I tell which WCF version I am running?

Tags: c#, wcf

I feel a little ridiculous for asking this question, but I have never really looked into it. I am trying to determine which version of WCF a project I have is using?

I see some of the common DLLs associated with WCF projects and ServiceModel which are 4.0, but not sure if I can make that assumption.

Comment: Should just be the project's target framework.  (Properties -> Target Framework)

Answer (score 14):

The version of WCF is tied to the version of .NET, so it is just "whatever version of .net you are running"

Comment: is this true? i still don't see this as an accepted answer.